# Junit5 with IntelliJ and Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

### Trying to migrate my project to java8 + Junit5 using `IntelliJ 2017.2`

I have added `junit-jupiter-api` version `5.0.0-M6`

and `junit-platform-launcher` version `1.0.0-M6`

Project structure is a default maven convention `src/test/java`

Found a couple articles about this but none of them did solve my issue.

**It runs nicely in a console, I presume this is something to do with the IntelliJ default JUnit Runner, or I am missing some dependencies?**

---

When I Run a  single test class all works fine but when I select the directory and `Run all 'Tests' in Java` like I used to do then I encounter few errors.

```
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.pruneTree()V

Aug 02, 2017 2:44:56 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.EngineDiscoveryRequest.getDiscoveryFiltersByType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/List;

Aug 02, 2017 2:44:56 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.pruneTree()V

Aug 02, 2017 2:44:56 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.EngineDiscoveryRequest.getDiscoveryFiltersByType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/List;
```

**Note**: I have not migrated any tests yet, all are Junit 4 syntax.

Comment: A general way to debug this is to run gradle test on the command-line. That should give more verbose output than IntelliJ.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Adding specific dependencies solve the problem.

**NOTE: UPDATE INTELLIJ ABOVE 2017.2.0 AS THERE WAS A BUG WITH THE JUNIT LAUNCHER**

**OXYGEN** if you using eclipse.

---

Below dependency enables Junit5 parametrized tests which can be used instead of a **DataProvider**.

```
"org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.0.0"
//for JUnit5 parametrized tests.
```

---

Junit5 **API**.

```
"org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0"
//JUnit5 API
```

---

Needed if you want to run legacy **JUnit4** tests without changing the syntax and imports.

```
"org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4:12.0"
//for legacy JUnit4 tests
```

**EDIT: 07/2018 Match the version of the vintage runner to the jupiter version**

---

Needed if you want to run **JUnit5** tests with new syntax and imports.

```
"org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0"
//for JUnit5 tests
```

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.EngineDiscoveryRequest.getDiscoveryFiltersByType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/List;

---

**Launcher**.

```
"org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.0
//to handle default launcher
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDefaultClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;

---

Additional info how to install [JUnit5](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/)

---

**Since version 4.6 for Gradle, there is no need for plugins anymore
Gradle supports Junit5 natively just do:**
And the version of the vintage runner is now same as the JUnit 5 version.

```
dependencies {

    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junitVersion"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion"

    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:$junitVersion"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion"
}

test {  
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeEngines 'junit-jupiter', 'junit-vintage'
    }
}
```

Comment: 2017.2.0 have the bug as well?

Comment: Could not find method test() for arguments ... Where to put test block?

Comment: Applied java or android plugin? Test task come through those plugins.

Comment: Adding `junit-platform-launcher` solved my problem.

Answer (score 17):

I have to change the version of JUnit from 5.4.0 for 5.3.2 and it works like a charm.

Comment: Same issue with JUnit 5.5.2.

Comment: The same for `5.5.1` too.

Comment: Same with 5.6.2

Answer (score 16):

The configuration I use is below.

The vintage engine dependency is only required if you are using junit4 tests as well.

The jupiter params is only required if using parameterised tests.

```
<properties>
    <junit.version>5.0.0</junit.version>
</properties>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>4.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your config worked for me. (I'm using intelliJ 2018.1)

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem using IntelliJ and jupiter in a corporate environment.
I was able to run 'mvn test', but starting tests in IntelliJ prompts 'IntelliJ failed to resolve junit platform launcher 1.5 2'

Configuring a HTTP Proxy fixed this for me:

Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Systems Settings -> HTTP Proxy -> Manual proxy configuration

Answer (score 0):

for android studio if you encounter

> Unable to resolve org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api

go to your file `..\AndroidStudioProjects\Pets\app\build.gradle`

at the dependencies section

input these two lines of code

```
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with junit 5.6.1 and **bumping it to 5.7.0** fixed it:

```
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0"
testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting behind a proxy server and maven clean install works fine(but not intellij), then most likely, it's proxy related. Here is what fixed it for me. Choosing proxy auto detection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Official docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven-engines-configure):

> Maven Surefire and Maven Failsafe can run JUnit 4 based tests
> alongside Jupiter tests as long as you configure test scoped
> dependencies on JUnit 4 and the JUnit Vintage TestEngine
> implementation similar to the following.
>
> ```
> <!-- ... -->
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>2.22.2</version>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>2.22.2</version>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
> <!-- ... -->
> <dependencies>
>     <!-- ... -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>junit</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>         <version>4.13</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
>         <version>5.7.2</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- ... -->
> </dependencies>
> <!-- ... -->
> ```

Answer (score 0):

use this annotation instead: org.junit.Test

also put your method and the corresponding class as public